# What are the conditions according to which the levitation force between a magnet and a superconducting material tends to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, superconductivity, levitation

According to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257595111_Size_Effects_on_Levitation_Force_Between_a_Magnet_and_a_Superconducting_Thin_Film_in_the_Meissner_State), for a disk-like superconductor and a magnet, if the radius of the superconductor tends to zero or the radius of the magnet tends to infinity, it seems that the levitation force approaches zero. (Cf. figures 4 and 5) However, I cannot trust my claim since the levitation forces in the article are calculated numerically for small variations of radii.

Are there any clear conditions according to which this force disappears? For instance, are there specific geometric shapes of the superconducting material for which no levitation force appears? Does this force vanish if we put a superconductor in a uniform magnetic field? Does it disappear if, say, [London penetration depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_penetration_depth) is assumed to be zero?